# pandas correlation between two string column

Tags: python, pandas

I am not sure if the title is correctly interprits what I want. let me explain.

please consider the `mwe` I am using

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("tmp.csv").astype('string')
print(dataset.head())
print(dataset.groupby('c2').size())
print(dataset.groupby('c1').size())
```

to read a csv file like:

```
name,c1,c2
foo,q1,p1
bar,q1,p2
qoo,q2,p1
soo,q3,p1
doo,q1,p1
too,q2,p2
```

Now, I want to find among all p1, how many of them belongs to q1, how many of them are in q2 and so on.
Like in above csv, out of 4 p1, 2 is from q1,1 is from q2 and 1 is from q3. I want to get that number and plot as a pie chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

you need `value_counts()`+`reset_index()`

```
out=df.value_counts(subset=['c2','c1']).reset_index(name='count')
```

output of `out`:

```
   c2   c1  count
0   p1  q1  2
1   p1  q2  1
2   p1  q3  1
3   p2  q1  1
4   p2  q2  1
```

If you need piechart(decorate it according to your need):

```
df.value_counts(subset=['c2','c1']).plot(kind='pie',autopct='%.2f%%')
```

output:

[image]